# MANADev SEO Layered Nav Plus - Search Results URL Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, search, catalogsearch

I have the MANADev Layered Navigation Plus extension for Magento 1.9.  The support period has expired or I'd ask them, but hopefully someone else has this and knows what to do.

I have it working great for all navigation pages as well as search, but search seems to be acting a little odd.  When you first search using Magento's stock search it takes you to **/catalogsearch/result?q=searchstring**.  If you then pick a layered nav filter, Mana takes over and the URL becomes **/search/[my-attribute]/[my-value]?q=searchstring**.  Then, if I remove that filter, instead of being taken back to **/catalogsearch/result** I'm taken to **/search?q=searchstring**.  For some reason, this actually works live, which is great, but it gives a 404 on my test machine.

I'm sure this is a simple config issue, I just don't understand what it's doing.  Furthermore, I'd much prefer consistency in the URLs.  Even if it works, the fact that "/catalogsearch/result?q=searchstring" is the exact same content as "/search?q=searchstring" is not good for SEO purposes.  How can I make this play well together?